# Reading large XML file with Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I'm having trouble reading a (somewhat) large XML file with Nokogiri, but can't figure out where things are going wrong. The file content looks like the following (just a single node included for readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0"><title>End | Globally Sourced Menswear</title><link type="self" link="http://www.endclothing.com/eu/"/><updated>2016-04-02T01:25:30+00:00</updated><entry><g:id>391</g:id><g:mpn>WRY3924TY</g:mpn><g:color>N/A</g:color><g:title>Comme des Garcons x Artek Standard Eau De Toilette</g:title><g:link>http://www.endclothing.com/eu/comme-des-garcons-x-artek-standard-eau-de-toilette-wry3924ty.html</g:link><g:price>89.00 EUR</g:price><g:availability>in stock</g:availability><g:brand>CDG Parfum</g:brand><g:custom_label_0>Perfume &amp; Fragrance</g:custom_label_0><g:condition>new</g:condition><g:description><![CDATA[<p>Founded by 4 young idealists in 1935, Finnish design company Artek produce modern furniture to promote the modern culture of habitation. Here they collaborate with <a href="/brands/comme-des-garcons-parfum">Comme des Garçons Parfum</a> to produce a fragrance dubbed 'Standard', ironic for a scent that is anything but.</p>
<span style="font-style:italic;">Notes Include:</span>
<ul>
<li>Thyme</li>
<li>Black Pepper</li>
<li>Patchouli</li>
<li>Cedar Wood</li>
<li>Citrus</li>
</ul>
<p>Due to recent changes in regulations, we are unable to ship aftershaves and perfumes to certain destinations outside of the EU. For full details, please email <a href="mailto:info@endclothing.co.uk?subject=Aftershave and Perfume Shipment">info@endclothing.co.uk</a> or call +44 191 231 3983.</p>]]></g:description><g:image_link>http://media.endclothing.com/media/catalog/product/1/8/18-03-2016_commedesgarcons_xartekstandardeaudetoilette_100ml_sh_1.jpg</g:image_link><g:additional_image_link>http://media.endclothing.com/media/catalog/product/1/8/18-03-2016_commedesgarcons_xartekstandardeaudetoilette_100ml_sh_2.jpg</g:additional_image_link><g:shipping><g:country>FR</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>DE</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>DK</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>NL</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>IT</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>SE</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>BE</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>AT</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>IE</g:country><g:service>Parcel Force Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>ES</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>LV</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>19.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>HR</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>35.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>CY</g:country><g:service>FEDEX Priority Service</g:service><g:price>45.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>HU</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>PT</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>19.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>EE</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>25.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>LU</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>9.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>SK</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>BG</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>25.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>GR</g:country><g:service>FEDEX Priority Service</g:service><g:price>25.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>PL</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>LT</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>19.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>SI</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>FI</g:country><g:service>Parcel Force Priority Service</g:service><g:price>19.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>CZ</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>LI</g:country><g:service>FEDEX Priority Service</g:service><g:price>35.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>MC</g:country><g:service>DPD Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping><g:shipping><g:country>CH</g:country><g:service>Parcel Force Priority Service</g:service><g:price>15.00 EUR</g:price></g:shipping></entry></feed>
```

I've tried the following code to read the stream, and while the separate parts seem to work just fine (`data` outputs a string which appears to be valid XML to me), Nokogiri appears to be unable to read the string, and just crashes or returns nothing for my xpath queries.

```
url = "http://www.endclothing.com/media/end_feeds/eu.xml.gz"
stream = open(url, 'Accept-Encoding' => 'gzip')
data = Zlib::GzipReader.new(stream).read
page = Nokogiri::XML(data)

page.xpath("//entry")
=> []
```

Comment: How large? Megabytes, Gigabytes, Terabytes?

Comment: 5MB gzipped, 250MB unzipped.

Comment: The universe is expanding so 250MB is no longer large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML has default namespace declared at the root element level :

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
```

In XML, descendant elements without prefix inherits default namespace from ancestor *implicitly*. That said, `entry` element that you tried to get is in the root element's default namespace.

On the other side, in XPath, element without prefix always considered in empty namespace. To reference element in XML's default namespace using XPath, we need to map a prefix to the default namespace URI and use that prefix in our XPath, for example :

```
page.xpath("//d:entry", 'd' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom')
```

Comment: Thanks so much for this, I had no idea about the namespaces. I ended up using page.remove_namespaces!.xpath("//entry") instead, but that was all thanks to your answer.